# Calculating Drawdown Based on Currency Pair Correlation

Tags: python, pandas, trading, quantitative-finance

The purpose of this program is to calculate the risk of hitting your max drawdown.
For example, if I had a portfolio consisting of EUR/USD at 1% risk and GBP/USD at 1% risk, and if EUR/USD gets stopped out, if GBP/USD is positively correlated to EUR/USD by a factor of 1, then I would lose 2% of my account balance since GBP/USD would get stopped out as well.

In reality, correlation in currencies is a spectrum, thus a more realistic example would be:

```
#max drawdown with 3 positions, EUR/USD long with 2% risk, USD/JPY long with .5% risk, and EUR/JPY short at 1% risk
  #drawdown = -2% + (corr(pair1, pair2) * -.5) + (corr(pair1, pair3) * -1)
  #drawdown = -2% + (-0.220332 * -.5) + (0.29804 * -1)
  #drawdown = -2% + 0.110166 + -0.29804
  #drawdown = -2.19 %
```

A few notes about this:

1. My formula starts with "-2%".  This is because EUR/USD is selected as the pivot currency, and the pivot currency will always have a 1 correlation with itself, so no correlation calculation is needed.
2. The correlation between every pair gets multiplied by the percentage of your account that you are risking.
3. They all get added together to produce a max drawdown, which is another way of saying, "If EUR/USD gets stopped out, I will lose 2% of my account balance, but what will my other positions do as a result, given that the other currencies are correlated in some way to EUR/USD?".

Above you can see my "pseudo code" which I am having trouble programming.  I just don't know where to start.

The program requires a portfolio sheet in csv format:

```
pair,risk,direction
EUR/USD,2,long
USD/JPY,.5,long
EUR/JPY,1,short
```

Here is the program code:

```
# %%
from twelvedata import TDClient
import os
import pandas as pd

# %%
td = TDClient(os.getenv('TD_API'))

# %%
all_symbols = ("AUD/CAD","AUD/CHF","AUD/JPY","AUD/NZD","AUD/USD",
               "CAD/CHF", "CAD/JPY", "CHF/JPY", 
               "EUR/AUD", "EUR/CAD", "EUR/CHF", "EUR/GBP", "EUR/JPY", "EUR/NZD", "EUR/USD",
               "GBP/AUD", "GBP/CAD", "GBP/CHF", "GBP/JPY", "GBP/NZD", "GBP/USD",
               "NZD/CAD", "NZD/CHF", "NZD/JPY", "NZD/USD", 
               "USD/CAD", "USD/CHF", "USD/JPY")

# %%
portfolio_sheet = pd.read_csv('portfolio_example.csv')
drawdown_tolerance = 4

# %%
for pair in portfolio_sheet['pair']:
    if pair in all_symbols:
      continue
    else:
      print("Symbol is not allowed or mispelled.  Please check the 'all_symbols' variable.")
      exit()

# %%
table = pd.DataFrame()

for _symbol in portfolio_sheet['pair']:
  ts = td.time_series(
    symbol = _symbol,
    interval="1day",
    outputsize="14"
  ).as_pandas()

  ts.drop(['open', 'high', 'low'], axis=1, inplace=True)
  ts.rename(columns={'close': str(_symbol)}, inplace=True)
  table = pd.concat([table, ts], axis=1)

print(table)
table = table.pct_change()
print(table)
print(table.corr())

# %%
#pseudo code:

#max drawdown with EUR/USD long 1% and USD/JPY long 1% in portfolio
  #drawdown = -1% + (corr(pair1, pair2) * -1%)
  #drawdown = -1% + (-0.187568) * -1%)
  #drawdown = -.81%

#max drawdown with 2 EUR/USD long positions at 1% risk each
  #drawdown = -1% + (corr(EUR/USD, EUR/USD) * -1%)
  #drawdown = -1% + (1.0 * -1%) 
  #drawdown = -2%

#max drawdown with 3 positions, EUR/USD long with 2% risk, USD/JPY long with .5% risk, and EUR/JPY short at 1% risk
  #drawdown = -2% + (corr(pair1, pair2) * -.5) + (corr(pair1, pair3) * -1)
  #drawdown = -2% + (-0.228452 * -.5) + (0.302295 * -1)
  #drawdown = -2% + 0.114226 + -0.302295
  #drawdown = -2.19 %

# %%
corr_counter = 1
pivot_risk = portfolio_sheet.iloc[0,1]
risk_counter = 2
drawdown = pivot_risk

# %%
for i in table.columns:
  for i in range(len(table.columns)-1):
    corr = table.iloc[:,0].corr(table.iloc[:,corr_counter])
    risk = corr * portfolio_sheet.iloc[risk_counter,1]
    if corr_counter < len(table.columns) -1:
      corr_counter += 1
  
  
  print("Risk is ",risk)
  print("Drawdown is ",drawdown)
  drawdown += risk
  print("Drawdown plus risk is ", drawdown)

  if risk_counter < len(portfolio_sheet) -1:
    risk_counter += 1
```

EDIT 3:

All print statements combined produce:

(this is just price data)

```
            EUR/USD    USD/JPY    EUR/JPY
datetime                                 
2023-08-28  1.08170  146.50500  158.47000
2023-08-25  1.07950  146.45500  158.10500
2023-08-24  1.08100  145.83501  157.66000
2023-08-23  1.08630  144.84500  157.34000
2023-08-22  1.08450  145.89000  158.23000
2023-08-21  1.08960  146.21500  159.31000
2023-08-18  1.08720  145.39500  158.06000
2023-08-17  1.08720  145.83501  158.56000
2023-08-16  1.08795  146.34500  159.22000
2023-08-15  1.09040  145.58000  158.75000
2023-08-14  1.09060  145.55499  158.75999
2023-08-11  1.09460  144.96001  158.70000
2023-08-10  1.09820  144.75500  158.96001
2023-08-09  1.09750  143.72501  157.73199
```

(this is the percentage changes in price data)

```
            EUR/USD   USD/JPY   EUR/JPY
datetime                                
2023-08-28       NaN       NaN       NaN
2023-08-25 -0.002034 -0.000341 -0.002303
2023-08-24  0.001390 -0.004233 -0.002815
2023-08-23  0.004903 -0.006789 -0.002030
2023-08-22 -0.001657  0.007215  0.005657
2023-08-21  0.004703  0.002228  0.006826
2023-08-18 -0.002203 -0.005608 -0.007846
2023-08-17  0.000000  0.003026  0.003163
2023-08-16  0.000690  0.003497  0.004162
2023-08-15  0.002252 -0.005227 -0.002952
2023-08-14  0.000183 -0.000172  0.000063
2023-08-11  0.003668 -0.004088 -0.000378
2023-08-10  0.003289 -0.001414  0.001638
2023-08-09 -0.000637 -0.007115 -0.007725
```

(this is the correlation table)

```
     EUR/USD   USD/JPY   EUR/JPY
EUR/USD  1.000000 -0.230169  0.299713
USD/JPY -0.230169  1.000000  0.859275
EUR/JPY  0.299713  0.859275  1.000000
```

(this is the output from the last for loop which is not correct because the risk cannot be .299 each time. The for loop is designed to do the same thing as the pseudo code written above)

```
Risk is  0.29971261173598107
Drawdown is  2.0
Drawdown plus risk is  2.299712611735981
Risk is  0.29971261173598107
Drawdown is  2.299712611735981
Drawdown plus risk is  2.599425223471962
Risk is  0.29971261173598107
Drawdown is  2.599425223471962
Drawdown plus risk is  2.899137835207943
```

As you can see the final "Drawdown plus risk" number should be the same number in the pseudo code which is 2.19.

Comment: What does "# %% (this block is not working)" mean?  What specifically is it expected to do, what does it do, what indicates the result is incorrect?

Comment: added more explanation

Comment: Code is working error free.  My only concern now is that my correlation table is incorrect.  Other correlation tables have GBP/USD and EUR/USD at 90+ correlation while mine is only at 56.  Any suggestions?

https://github.com/kirillmcclintock/fx_correlation_risk_management